# Destroying linked list, why is this working?

Tags: c, linked-list, valgrind

I've created this function that destroys a linked list, `head` is the head of the linked list.

```
void destroy(node** head){

    node* current = NULL;
    while(*head != NULL){
        current = *head;
        free(current);
        *head = (*head)->next;
    }

}
```

I thought that this code won't work because `head` and `current` point to the same address in memory, and since it was freed, you can't access `(*head)->next`. But when I ran the program it worked fine, when I checked the list was empty.

I even ran a valgrind test on the program, there was no memory leaks, although there is few cryptic errors.

Why is this code working ? It does not seem intuitive.

Comment: Use after free is undefined behavior, which means it can do anything.  It may appear to work on some implementations, it may cause errors on others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought that this code won't work because `*head` and `current` point to the same address in memory, and since it was freed, you can't access `(*head)->next`

That's exactly right: once you `free(current)` the access to `(*head)->next` is *undefined behavior*.

Unfortunately, undefined behavior is not equivalent to a crash, so one may get an impression that the program is working; it is not!

> I even ran a valgrind test on the program, there was no memory leaks, although there is few cryptic errors.

This is not a memory leak, but an access to freed memory. It does result in a somewhat cryptic error message - something along these lines:

> Address `0x5a02048` is 4 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd

What this means is that `sizeof(node)` is 16, and the offset of `next` is 4.

Obviously, the right way of freeing the list is to swap the lines that access `next` and call `free(current)`.

```
while(*head != NULL){
    node* current = *head;
    *head = (*head)->next;
    free(current);
}
```

Note that `current` can be declared inside the loop.

Comment: Just a change of name from `current` to `victim` makes the logic abundantly clear `:)`

Answer (score 1):

The code has **undefined behavior** as you access memory you have just `free`'d.

The real bad thing about undefined behavior is that it **may appear** to work even though the code has undefined behavior.

Change the code to:

```
void destroy(node** head){   
    node* current = NULL;
    while(*head != NULL){
        current = *head;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(current);
    }
}
```

so that you change `*head` before calling `free`

Answer (score 0):

It works because, in this particular case, the freed memory has not been modified, even though it is free and you no longer own it.

Don't do this. On another compiler or platform, maybe it will be modified, or maybe an illegal memory access error will occur, or maybe you'll be changing memory used by another part of your program. That makes this a bad approach. Only use memory that your program owns,

Comment: What's a better alternative ?

Comment: You can loop through the list, obtaining the next item, and not freeing the current item until you have the next item

Answer (score 0):

Here is the my solution :

```
void destroy(node** head){   
                node* current = *head;
                while((*head) != NULL){
                        if((*head)->next!=NULL)
                                *head = (*head)->next;
                        else { /* if next node is NULL, free it and comes out of loop or function  **/
                                (*head) = NULL;
                                free(current);
                                current = NULL;/* to avoid Dangling pointer problem **/
                                break;//or return bcz there will not be further node to delete **/
                        }
                        /** below 2 statements will execute only if part is true **/
                        free(current);
                        current = *head;
                }
        }
```